# /etc/profile doesn't seem to be sourced in any situation

Tags: bash, shell, login, etc

I added these to `/etc/profile` (Ubuntu 15.10).

```
PATH=$PATH:/my/bin
date > /tmp/etc_profile_date
```

When I graphical login, `/my/bin` is not in `PATH` and `/tmp/etc_profile_date` has not been created.

When I terminal-only login, neither is there.

When I `su - myusername`, neither is there.

When I `ssh myusername@localhost`, neither is there.

If I `source /etc/profile` manually, the file and `PATH` are as expected.

Why do none of the above situations source `/etc/profile`? It seems to contradict what I'm reading elsewhere. It also works as expected on CentOS.

Comment: Ubuntu, as I said in the first line of the question.

Comment: If I add `echo "/etc/profile read"` at the start of the file, it gets printed when I do `bash -l` in a terminal/console. Could you report what you get?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that my login shell in /etc/passwd is zsh, but there is a known bug in which zsh doesn't source /etc/profile. It looks like they won't fix this because they would have to break other functionality in zsh.